# Auto-complete Textbox not working

Tags: c#, mysql, autocomplete

I have this kind of textbox that I use to search for data in a database. I tried to use AutoComplete to it but for some reason, it's not working. I tried on different variations but nothing works well for me though.

```
private void AutoCompleteSearch()
    {
        AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand commands = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ItemCode FROM addinv_table", conn);
        conn.Open();
        myReader = commands.ExecuteReader();
        if (myReader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while(myReader.Read())
            {
                stringCollection.Add(myReader["ItemCode"].ToString());
            }
        }
        myReader.Close();
        textBox2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = stringCollection;
    }
```

Keep in mind that AutoCompleteSearch() was called every time the Form loads.

Comment: are you sure you got something from the db?

Comment: Under your **while loop** please add the following: `Console.WriteLine(myReader["ItemCode"].ToString());` let us know what prints out in the console (if anything).

Comment: The autocomplete seem very straight forward. You can first use a hard code list of data to test it and then add the db component. Here is an example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2suYQr6ebI

Comment: @MasterYoda it displayed all the data, by ItemCode, from my database table

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I already watched that. Even hard coding the list doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Form.Load is often too soon.